# How to use Java Optional to protect from reading uninitialized array?

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, option-type

I've got the uninitialized array

```
static String arr[];
```

And trying to protect from reading it by using `Optional`

```
Optional.ofNullable(arr[0]).ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Unfortunately I've got `java.lang.NullPointerExeption`

How to use `Optional` properly?

It's for educational purposes only. I know I can check it in just standard if. I just want to learn using Optionals.

My goal is to write oneliner which is printing the first element of the array if it is not null and if the whole array is initialized.

Comment: Optional.ofNullable(arr).ifPresent((p)->{System.out.println(p[0]);});

Comment: @SarelFoyerlicht won't work if array is empty

Comment: Just about what happened: ```Optional.ofNullable()``` is a regular static method (it has no extra features from this point of view), and ```arr[0]``` is an argument you pass to it. It (```arr[0]```) dies if ```arr``` is ```null```, even before anything happens with the method call.

Comment: Optional.ofNullable(arr).ifPresent((p)-> Optional.ofNullable(p[0]).ifPresent((first)->{System.out.println(first);}));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need something like this:

```
Optional.ofNullable(arr)
        .flatMap(x -> Arrays.stream(x).findFirst())
        .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Why use `Arrays.stream(x).findFirst()` when you can just use `x[0]`?

Comment: `x[0]` might not exist and you'll get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException which is no better than original NPE.

Comment: You're right. I was assuming that `arr` may or may not be null, but that if it wasn't null that it would definitely have elements (it would be unusual to assign it with a zero-length array, but not impossible)

Answer (score 1):

Another very simple alternative:

```
   Optional.ofNullable(arr)
      .filter(a -> a.length > 0)
      .map(a -> a[0])
      .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

The filter ensures that the array isn't empty. Thus it's safe to map to the first element of the array.

It even looks similar to the standard way:

```
if (arr != null && arr.length > 0) {
  System.out.println(arr[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Optional.ofNullable(arr_v_[0]).ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

it fails due to NPE where `_v_`is - `arr` is null thus `NPE`

`if(arr!=null)` should be enough for you.

Comment: Ok, I get it. I'm passing literally null to the Optional, not an object containing null, yes? But how to do it properly? How to make this function works?

Comment: What do you want to check? Ommitting array index will give you a hit if array is initialized or not.

Comment: My goal is to learn Optional. I know how to do it using if. Just want to write oneliner wchich is printing the first element of array if it is not null, and if the whole array is initialized.

Comment: You can wrap everything into one line. Besides if is shorter than using Optional here so you would lose golf code competition

Answer (score 0):

You cannot iterate over an not initialized Array, because is a NULL object. There a lot of good answers that already resolve the question but I think is better to understand that it will work if you initialize first you array.

```
String arr[] = new String[5];
Optional.ofNullable(arr[0]).ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Will work. Because you have a arr of String with nulls.

```
   String arr[] ; 
Optional.ofNullable(arr[0]).ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Will not work because you have a Null Object. You will need to make an workaround for checking first if the array is null.